# Real Analysis Proof Help

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

Prove that if a > 0 then there exists n as an element N such that 1/n < a < n. I know the answer involves the Archimedean Property, but I'm not sure how to write the proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider two cases: If $a > 1$, choose $n$ to be any natural number greater than $a$.

If $a < 1$, let $n$ be any natural number greater than $\frac 1 a$.

Comment: (I think you mean $1/a$ instead of $1/n$.

Comment: @user84413 Yes, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Archimedean property says that there exist an $n_0\in\mathbb N$ such that $\frac1{n_0}\lt a$. 

If $n_0>a$ we are done. Else we can take $n=\lfloor a\rfloor+1$ (why?).

Answer (score 0):

With $a \gt 0$ and $(1 \gt 0)∈R$ then there is $n_1 ∈ N$ such that $n_1 \gt a$.
Also there is $n_2 \in N$ such that $a(n_2)$ \gt 1 so $1 \lt a(n_2)$ i.e $\frac{1}{n_2} \lt a$.

So we have $\frac{1}{n_2} \lt  a \lt n_1$. Now let $n = \max(n_1, n_2)$.

It is clear that $\frac{1}{n} \lt a < n$.

Comment: Please use MathJaX formatting to make this readable and more helpful.